# What connection string to use to read sqlite db from powerpivot using SQLite ODBC driver

Tags: sqlite, odbc, connection-string, powerpivot

I'd like to import that data contained in a sqlite file to PowerPivot. I downloaded an ODBC driver for sqlite (http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/) to accomplish this. In PowerPivot I selected "Home" > "Get External Data" > "From Other Sources". I scrolled down to "Others (OLEDB/ODBC). Selected it and clicked next.

TheFor the connection string. I found this website: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite and I tried the connection string at the bottom suggested for SQLite3 ODBC Driver:

```
DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=c:\Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;
SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;
```

(I'm using a sample database that I put at the root of my c:. The db if from here: http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/releases/view/55169 )

With this connection string when I Test the Connection I get the following error message:

> The test connection failed because the provider could not be initialized. If you contact Microsoft support about this error, provide the following message: Faile to connect to server. Reason: Provider information is missing from the connection string. Add the provider information and try again.

I understand that the driver I installed is not found, but I don't know how to correct the connection string to point to the driver dll.

Comment: ur connection string lack of this : providerName="...abcdfgh..."

Comment: Where can I find the providerName? Sorry I'm new to connection strings and Databases :S

Comment: Hi @TristanBoudreault, it's been 2 years since you posed the question, did you manage to get a solution? I am facing the exact same issue. Would appreciate if you could share your solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NoviceProg I haven't found a solution sadly. I gave up and decided to changed my tools, I used python instead to manipulate the data.

Comment: @TristanBoudreault, I managed to resolve the issue after much research and trial-and-error. Please select it as the answer so that others facing it may be directed here in future.

Answer (score 6):

This solution came after many hours of research and trial-and-error. Though it came 2 years late, I am putting it up to help others trying to import information to Power Pivot 2013 from SQLite.

Step 1: Install SQLite ODBC Driver from [here](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).

Step 2: Create a DNS by opening Windows' 'ODBC Data Sources Administrator' (you can find it under Windows > Administrative Tools). See [here](http://web.synametrics.com/SQLite.htm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277537/unable-to-connect-access-to-sqllite-via-odbc) for more information. I have tried creating the DNS under both 'User DNS' and 'System DNS' - both work fine with Power Pivot.

Step 3: Open Power Pivot and do the following:

Click 'From other Sources' > 'Others (OLEDB/ODBC)' > Click on 'Build' button >
Under 'Provider' tab > Select '**MS OLE DB Provider for ODBC Sources**' > In 'Use Data Source Name', select your DNS created in Step 2 and add any other parameters. At this point, you can test the connection and it should say 'Test Connection Succeeded'

Once you click 'OK', you should see the Connection String automatically generated. Mine was: 'Provider=MSDASQL;Persist Security Info=False;DSN=SQLiteTest'.

Follow the next few steps to import your data from SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Mode=ReadWrite;Initial Catalog=C:\XXX.db;DSN=SQLite3 Datasource
```