# Unable to connect Access to SQLlite via ODBC

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 97 database that serves as a front-end, via ODBC and linked tables, to a MySQL database, running under Wiin7-64. (Yes, it does work!) The database contains info about places of worship and pilgrimage in the part of France where I live. In addition, I have tens of thousands of photos of the sites in Photoshop Elements 9. The underlying database engine of PSE9 is SQLite, and interesting data about the photos is there (titles, which ones I like, etc.). I would like to link from Access to the tables in the SQLite database as I do to the MySQL database.

My problem: I am unable to create an ODBC connection to the PSE9 SQLite database. I have done multiple searches via Google, read multiple posts at stackoverflow and elsewhere, tried various suggestions, and still no ODBC connection, neither in the 32bit or 64bit ODBC tools of Win7-64. I'm stumped.

So far, I've

- downloaded sqliteodbc.exe from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/ and run it (multiple times)
- copied sqlite3odbc.dll, sqlite3.def, sqlite3.dll, and sqlite3.exe to the \windows\system32 folder
- entered this command at the Windows command line: "rundll32 c:\windows\system32\sqlite3odbc.dll,install", which produced this error message "Copy c:\windows\system32\sqlite3odbc.dll to c:\windows\system32\sqlite3odbc.dll failed."

When I look at the ODBC and ODBC (32-bit) windows, I don't find a User DSN, System DSN or File DSN for SQLite.  Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Harvey in balmy Bordeaux

Answer (score 3):

Whats with all that copying dlls around - you don't need to do any of that. Just download the 32 bit version and double click on it - the driver will be installed. Then find the 32 bit ODBC Administrator (note there are 2 on 64 bit windows and only one is 32 bit), fire it up and create a DSN. You should see sqlite3 in the drivers tab.

Comment: I thought I said I'd done that.  SQLite3 is not in the drivers tab.

Comment: bohica, I think owe you an apology.  You're right that I hadn't specified I had clicked on all the Add buttons in all the places where one could add a DSN.

Answer (score 2):

DSNs are not there automatically, you have to create them yourself. There should be an "Add" button in the ODBC administrator. Then you select the type of driver "SQLite", and then configure the details in the next dialog.

A DSN normally contains all the configuration information needed to connect to a specific database instance so that all this - which may be different from one database system to the other - can be referenced by one name. That is where the name "Data Source Name" comes from.

Comment: FrankPI,

As I tried to suggest in my post, when I go to the ODBC administrator and click on the Add button, there is no SQLite driver in the list.  And this is true, whether I try under the User DSN, System DSN, or File DSN tabs in either the 32-bit ODBC administrator or the 64-bit ODBC administrator.

Harvey

Comment: Then your installation did not work. You write that you got an error message during install. Maybe you will have to re-run this as administrator, and move the dll to another place so that it can copy itself to where it wants.

Comment: Problem solved: I found two sqlite routines (sqliteodbc.dll and sqliteodbcu.dll) in the SysWOR64 folder, renamed them and reran sqliteodbc.exe sucessfully.  Then started Access 97, clicked on the New table button, selected Link Table and selected file type ODBC database.  In the Select Data Source window that opened, I clicked on the New button and selected the SQLite3 ODBC driver I now found.  It was downhill from there.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: That should have been SysWOW64 folder.